# Cannot push an object into a null array

Tags: postgresql

So basically I'm trying to push an object into this array:

[image: null array]

But as I discovered recently, you can't push something to a null array, apparently I need to initialize it or something. Any help?

Comment: You said it. You need to inizialize it, then if you add some code something can be suggested, in this way the question is too much generic

Comment: This has nothing to do with code. I'm getting an error that tells me pushing an object into a null array is impossible. Until I can change this array from null to nonnull, all code is meaningless. So, how to initialize the array?

Comment: With code, like a default value in a create table or something in a sql procedure, some client code that generates the sql script you are executing, a gui tool that connect to the db, these are the ways I could think of, giving some context on what you are doing will help

Comment: I'm also curious ro know how you are getting that error if "it has nothing to do with code"

Comment: The problem is not with the code, it does its intended job. The problem is that I don't know how to use pgAdmin, specifically how to turn null array into a nonnull array. It's that simple.

Comment: "*how to turn null array into a nonnull array*" - you do that like with any other (null) value, e.g. by using `coalesce()` or by replacing it with a non-null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a value to an array that is NULL, and it will work as you expect it to work:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   x text[] := NULL;
BEGIN
   x[1] := 'hello';
   RAISE NOTICE 'x = %', x;
END;$$;

NOTICE:  x = {hello}
```

But it is easy to replace the NULL value with an empty array:

```
UPDATE tab
SET posts = ARRAY[]
WHERE id = 42;
```

A comment on your data model: don't use an array to store a list of posts. Use a separate table with a foreign key to your table, and have each post be a table row. That will be easier to use and perform much better.